# how to avoid overlap of div elements when window is resized

Tags: html, css, oracle-adf

I have created two div elements which has width of 100% and Halign and Valign set to stretch. On resize the content of the top element overlaps the beginning portion of the bottom element. I cannot set position to absolute because the AF Stretch property disappears in that case. Any suggestions on what I can do? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please show some code

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are mixing HTML code with ADF tags.
While this is possible when using facelets, is not advisable if you are not an ADF expert.

To come up with a proper solution you will need to understand how internally ADF tags are rendering HTML output. Even if you get away with it, you can't be certain that in the future ADF versions the output of ADF components won't be changed - so your layout will break once again.

If you want o adapt a certain layout, you can use a af:panelHeader,  af:panelBox instead, then start playing with ADF Skining to bring up your required layout. I have used this approach for different layouts myself, ADF adapts to pretty much any Look and Feel as long as you  use skinning.